# RFC 5322 Standard email validation regular expression

Tags: javascript, php, regex

I need to implement same email validation in client side and server side(PHP).
Email Validation must follow the **RFC 5322 Standard** and I spent much time on the internet but I did not found. so please help me.

Actually, I confused about the email pattern because FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL is not allowing 'test@example' and In Jquery Validator, 'test@example' is allowing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
^\w+([.]\w+)*@\w+([.]\w+)+$
```

[Here Is Demo](https://regex101.com/r/q3zmYa/1)

Comment: For PHP or Javascript?

Comment: That is just the regular expression.

Comment: Actually, I confused about the email pattern because FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL is not allowing 'test@example' and In Jquery Validation, 'test@example' is allowing.

Comment: ut Please help me?

Comment: Please, have a look at these sites: [TLD list](https://www.iana.org/domains/root/db); [valid/invalid addresses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Examples); [regex for RFC822 email address](http://www.ex-parrot.com/~pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html)

Comment: Very thanks Todo. Can you share regex for PHP and Javascript?